# Given $d \equiv 5 \pmod {10}$, prove $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})}$ never has unique factorization

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory, unique-factorization-domains

With the exception of $d = 5$, which gives $\mathbb{Z}[\phi]$, of course (as was explained to me in another question). I'm not concerned about $d$ negative here, though that might provide a clue I have overlooked.

What I thought about was the fact that $2, 3, 7$ are irreducible in such a domain. But that does not necessarily guarantee that at least one of $6, 14, 21$ is going to have an alternate distinct factorization. I also have this vague inkling that $5$ being prime has something to do with it.

---

**EDIT:** Oops, sorry, I forgot to specify $d$ is squarefree. Thank you for forgiving this little mistake.

Comment: We may need to modify things in order to rule out numbers like $d=45$.

Comment: I think he just forgot to write "$d$ squarefree."

Comment: Definitely. His mention of $\textbf{Z}[\phi]$ makes it clear he's aware of the concept of integral closure. If $n$ squarefree is such that $\mathcal{O}_{\textbf{Q}(\sqrt{n})}$ is UFD, then setting $d = 5n^2$ or $d = 25n$ or anything like that then you get something that closes to a UFD. I hope he doesn't get severely penalized for this minor oversight, something that happens quite often on this site.

Comment: And bravo for such a deceptively simple question!

Comment: @Jyrki Do you think this question can be answered with basic methods like what Anthony tried, or are more advanced methods like in your attempt required?

Comment: @RobertSoupe: I don't know. However, I can fix my argument.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following proof uses ideas due to Ennola (Two elementary proofs 
concerning simple quadratic fields) and Redei (Über die 
quadratischen Zahlkörper mit Primzerlegung) and can be used to show 
that a necessary condition for  ${\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{m})$ to have unique factorization is that its discriminant is prime or a product of two negative prime discriminants.

Assume that $K = {\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{5m})$ has unique factorization 
and consider the ideal $P = (5,\sqrt{m})$. Then $P^2 = (5)$. Since
$K$ has unique factorization, $P$ is principal, hence there exists 
$\pi \in {\mathcal O}_K$ with $P = (\pi)$. From $P^2 = (\pi^2) = (5)$
we deduce that there exists a unit $\eta \in {\mathcal O}_K$ with
$\pi^2 = 5\eta$.

If $m < 0$, then $\eta = \pm 1$, hence $\sqrt{5} \in K$ or 
$\sqrt{-5} \in K$: contradiction.

If $m > 0$, then either $\eta = 1$ and $m = 1$, i.e., 
$K = {\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{5})$, or $\eta \ne 1$. In the second case
we have $m > 1$, and we may assume that $\eta$ is the fundamental
unit (squares of units may be subsumed into $\pi$). Then there 
is a prime $q \mid m$, and as above we find that $q\eta = \lambda^2$. 
This implies $\sqrt{5q} \in K$, hence $K$ is the product of two 
prime discriminants. In addition, $25N(\eta) = N(5\eta) = N(\pi^2) = 25$
implies that $N\eta = +1$, so the fundamental unit has norm $+1$.

Since $q \equiv 1 \bmod 4$ (discriminants are never $\equiv 3 \bmod 4$)
we can write $5q = a^2 + b^2$ with $a$ odd.  Setting $\alpha = b + \sqrt{5q}$
and $Q = (a,\alpha)$ we find from $\alpha \alpha' = -a^2$ that
$Q^2 = (a^2,2a\alpha,\alpha^2) = (\alpha\alpha',2a\alpha,\alpha^2) = 
  (\alpha)(\alpha',2a, \alpha) = (\alpha)$ since $\alpha$ and $\alpha'$
are coprime as ideals. Since $Q = (\omega)$ is principal, the element
$\omega^2/\alpha$ is a unit with negative norm: contradiction.

In the proof we have used that unique factorization holds if and only
if $h = 1$. If $P = (5,\sqrt{5m})$ is not principal, then 
$5 \cdot m = \sqrt{5m} \cdot \sqrt{5m}$ is an example of non-unique
factorization. If $P$ is principal (e.g. when $m = 41$), then
$-a^2 = (b+\sqrt{5m})(b-\sqrt{5m})$ should give rise to an example
of non-unique fasctorization, but I haven't checked the details.

Comment: Given that my first course in algebraic number theory was from Veikko Ennola I'm a bit ashamed of not having encountered this result. Sadly, he passed away about 2½ years ago (at the age of 81 IIRC).

Comment: @Jyrki Wikipedia cites Neukirch for that, but there are plenty others that could be cited. Is the Redei paper recent and is it available in English?

Comment: Jyrki - thanks, I corrected the first paragraph now. Redei's article is in German, but the proof above works just as well for all composite discriminants.

Answer (score 7):

[Now fixed and completed :-)]

I think the following roundabout argument works when $d\equiv 5\pmod{10}$ is square-free.

Assume $d>0$. My solution needs some facts from class field theory, because the basic idea is to show that $K=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{d},\sqrt5)$ is a quadratic, unramified, totally real extension of $L=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt d)$. As $K/L$ is abelian, class field theory then implies that $K$ is contained in [the Hilbert class field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_class_field) $H$ of $L$. But it is known that $[H:L]=h$ is the class number of $L$, so we get as a by-product that the class number of $L$ is even. The immediate corollary is that $\mathcal{O}_L$ cannot be a UFD.

Write $d=5a$. The claim follows from a calculation of discriminants, but the details of the calculation differ according to the residue class of $a$ modulo $4$.

**Case I.** I assume first that $a\equiv-1\pmod4$, or that $d\equiv-5\pmod{20}$. It is well known that $\Delta_{L/\Bbb{Q}}=4d=20a$, because $d\not\equiv1\pmod4$. On the other hand $K$ contains $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$ and $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{a})$ as subfields. So if we denote $\phi=(1+\sqrt{5})/2$ we know that the $\Bbb{Z}$-span of $S=\{1,\phi,\sqrt a,\phi\sqrt a\}=\{s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4\}$ is contained in $\mathcal{O}_K$. Therefore the determinant of the matrix $A=(tr(s_is_j)_{1\le i,j\le 4})$ has the discriminant $D=\Delta_{K/\Bbb{Q}}$ as a factor. But, unless I made a mistake
$$
A=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
4&2&0&0\\
2&6&0&0\\
0&0&4a&2a\\
0&0&2a&6a\end{array}\right),
$$
and this has determinant $400a^2=(4d)^2$. Because the relative discriminant $\Delta_{K/L}$ (necessarily viewed as an ideal) satisfies [the relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant_of_an_algebraic_number_field)
$$
D=N_{L/\Bbb{Q}}(\Delta_{K/L})(\Delta_{L/\Bbb{Q}})^2=16d^2 N_{L/\Bbb{Q}}(\Delta_{K/L})\mid\det A= 16d^2,
$$
we can conclude that $S$ must be an integral basis and that the relative discriminant is $1$. The claim follows.

**Case II.** Assume next that $a\equiv 1\pmod 4$, $a\neq1$. This time $d\equiv1\pmod4$, and we know that $d(L/\Bbb{Q})=d=5a$. Again $K$ has the subfields $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt 5)$ and $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt a)$, but this time both of them have "smaller" algebraic integers. If we abbreviate $\theta=(1+\sqrt a)/2$, we know that $S=\{s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4\}=\{1,\phi,\theta,\phi\theta\}$ is a set of algebraic integers of $K$, linearly independent over $\Bbb{Z}$. This time the matrix
$$
A=(tr^K_{\Bbb{Q}}(s_is_j))_{1\le  i,j\le4}
=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
4&2&2&1\\
2&6&1&3\\
2&1&1+a&\frac{1+a}2\\
1&3&\frac{1+a}2&\frac{3(1+a)}2\end{array}\right).
$$
Again we are lucky, and $\det A=25a^2=d(L/\Bbb{Q})^2.$ The claim follows as in Case I.

---

A similar argument shows that $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{d},i)/\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt d)$ is unramified at all finite primes. Initially I mistakenly thought that this again implies that the Hilbert class field of $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt d)$ contains $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{d},i)$. However, the infinite primes fail here unless we also have $d<0$, so this does not follow (unless $d<0$ which was excluded in the question).

---

But, the claim also holds when $d<0$. The above calculations of discriminants are immune to the sign of $d$. The only change is in the class field theoretical parts. Because $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt d)$ is now totally imaginary, the question about the ramification of the infinite prime does not arise at all! The claim holds for all $d\equiv5\pmod {10}, d\neq 5.$

Comment: Can we locate an expert who can translate this to an example of a failed unique factorization?

Comment: Probably somebody here has calculated the discriminant of the compositum of two quadratic fields. I couldn't find a related question or a reference.

Comment: Not an expert talking here: I have a hunch that as long as $d \not\equiv 2 \pmod 3$, we can rely on 6 to have more than one distinct factorization. Otherwise we probably have to look to 14 or 21.

Comment: Not sure, @Robert. For some choices of $d$ or $a$ both $3$ and $7$ will be inert, and thus principal in $\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt d)}$. I don't think we should expect a finite set of primes to cover all the possible values of $d$ here. Residue classes modulo $d$ or $4d$ enter the equation somehow.

Comment: Trying desperately to trace this back to the Artin map. If a non-principal prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ of $L$ lies above the rational prime $p$, then the non-trivial automorphism of $Gal(K/L)$ should somehow be related to the Frobenius automorphism at $\mathfrak{p}$. To me this suggests looking for a $p$ that splits in $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt d)$ and is inert in both $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt5)$ and $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt a)$. But this may be a false lead (just comparing what happens above $p=3$ when $a=-1$).

Answer (score 4):

This is an attempt to translate the argument of my "class field theoretic" answer to more elementary language. Leaving both answers here for future reference (mostly for my own benefit, but if you take this as an advertisement, and are encouraged to study class field theory, that will bring joy to my heart). This answer relies on the fact that it suffices to show that the ring of integers is not a PID. For a proof of this fact on-site see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1244805/11619).

Dirichlet's result of infinitude of primes in an arithmetic progression is also used - in the much weaker form -  I need the existence of a single prime in the progression.

Starting out with the case of a square-free positive $d$, $d\equiv -5\pmod{20}$ - again first an answer that covers only half the possibilities for $d$.

Write $d=5a$. The assumption $d\equiv-5\pmod{20}$ means that $a\equiv3\pmod4$. I claim that there exists a prime $p$ such that both $5$ and $a$ are quadratic non-residues modulo $p$. To this end we need the existence part of Dirichlet's theorem.

Let the prime factorization of $a$ be $a=p_1p_2\cdots p_k$. Because $d=5a$ is square-free, all primes $p_i$ are odd, distinct and $\neq5$. At least one of them is $\equiv 3\pmod4$, so w.l.o.g. we can assume that $p_1\equiv 3\pmod 4$.
Consider the following system of congruences
$$
\begin{aligned}
p&\equiv1\pmod 4,\\
p&\equiv 2\pmod5,\\
p&\equiv -1\pmod {p_1},\\
p&\equiv 1\pmod {p_i},\ \text{for all $i=2,3,\ldots,k$.}
\end{aligned}
$$
The moduli in this system are pairwise coprime, so by the Chinese Remainder Theorem they are satisfied by a single residue class modulo $20a$. That residue class is clearly coprime to all prime factors of $20a$, so Dirichlet applies. We can thus infer that a prime $p$ satisfying all these congruences exists.

Given all those congruences the law of quadratic reciprocity implies that $5$ and $p_1$ are quadratic non-residues modulo $p$, and all the primes $p_2,p_3,\ldots,p_k$ are quadratic residues modulo $p$ (the first congruence is there simply to ensure that $(-1)^{(p-1)/2}=1$, and hence quadratic reciprocity plays out nicely). By the multiplicativity of the Legendre symbol we then get our claim: 
$$
\left(\frac5p\right)=-1,\qquad\left(\frac{a}p\right)=-1.
$$
A consequence of these is that $\left(\dfrac dp\right)=1$.

This last fact implies that the rational prime ideal $(p)$ splits in $L=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt d)$. Let $\mathfrak{p}$ be one of the prime ideals of $\mathcal{O}_L$ lying above $p$. I claim that $\mathfrak{p}$ cannot be a principal ideal.

The ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_L$ consists of numbers $z=x+y\sqrt d$ with $x,y\in\Bbb{Z}$. If we make the contrapositive assumption that $\mathfrak{p}=\langle z\rangle$, then a calculation of norms implies that
$$
N(z)=x^2-dy^2=x^2-5ay^2=\pm p.
$$
But reducing this equation modulo $5$ we get the congruence
$$
x^2\equiv\pm2\pmod 5,
$$
which we know to be impossible. This is a contradiction, so $\mathfrak{p}$ is not principal, and $\mathcal{O}_L$ is not a PID.

Comment: I don't think you used that $p_1 \equiv 3 \bmod 4$ anywhere, so this is  a proof in the $a \equiv 1 \bmod 4$ case as well. More precisely, you have to allow for the possibility that $x$ and $y$ are both half integers in the final computation, but the computation still goes through.

Comment: Thanks, @David. I thought I would need to do the case $a\equiv1\pmod4$ separately exactly because of those half-integers. As it happened I was just thinking about how to modify the argument :-)

Comment: @DavidSpeyer: On second thought, I did use the fact that $p_1\equiv-1\pmod4$. The argument about splitting of $p$ needs that
$$\left(\frac{p_1}p\right)=\left(\frac p{p_1}\right)=\left(\frac{-1}{p_1}\right)=-1,$$ and the last step holds only if $p_1\equiv -1\pmod4$. Of course, I can use any quadratic non-residue in place of $-1$, I think :-)

Comment: Oh, yes. You also need to replace $-1$ by some nonresidue mod $p_1$, as you say.