# Why the flip between prime and maximal/irreducible?

Tags: ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $R$ be an integral domain.

Prime elements and prime ideals in $R$ are connected by:

$a$ prime element $\iff$ $(a)$ prime ideal

Irreducible elements and ideal maximality in $R$ are connected by:

$a$ irreducible element $\iff$ $(a)$ maximal in the set of proper principal ideals

Note that $(a)$ is not exactly a maximal ideal, unless $R$ is a PID.

We have the implication when looking at elements:

prime element $\implies$ irreducible element

But there seems to be a flip in the implication when looking at ideals:

maximal ideal $\implies$ prime ideal

Is this expected when switching between elements versus ideals?

If $R$ is a PID, we do have:

prime element $\iff$ irreducible element

maximal ideal $\iff$ (nonzero) prime ideal

Comment: Yuu may find helpful the six equivalent statements in [this Theorem.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1245196/242)