# Is there are two prime elements which generate a proper ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, unique-factorization-domains

Let $A$ be a UFD, we know $A$ is a PID iff $A$ is a Bezout domain. Now I want to consider the case
$A$ is not a PID.

So the question is that does **every** UFD $A$ which is not PID admit two distinct prime elements $a,b$ such that $(a,b)\neq A.$

Comment: See $(4)$ in [this Theorem in the dupe](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1245196/242)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the answer, but I will take a stab at the proof myself. Hope that this proof is either correct, or someone will be able to point to a mistake, in which case I will pull it out.

---

**Lemma**: If $p,q,r$ are three elements of a commutative ring $R$ with unity such that $(p,r)=(q,r)=R$, then $(pq,r)=R$ as well.

**Proof**: if $1=ap+br=cq+dr$ for some $a,b,c,d\in R$, then:

$$q=apq+brq$$
$$1=cq+dr=c(apq+brq)+dr=(ac)pq+(bq+d)r$$
$\blacksquare$

From there, using induction and symmetry, we can prove our statement.

Let $R$ be UFD which is not a Bezout domain. This means that there are two elements $p,q$ such that $(p,q)$ is not principal.

WLOG we can assume that $p,q$ are coprime. Otherwise, take $d=\gcd(p,q)$ and then $p/d, q/d$ are coprime and the ideal $(p/d, q/d)$ is already not principal.

Now, let $p=p_1\cdots p_n, q=q_1\cdots q_m$ where all $p_i, q_j$ are prime and none of the $p_i$'s is the same as any of the $q_j$'s. Now:

- Either one of $(p_i, q_j)$ is a proper ideal, in which case we are done. (That ideal cannot be principal because $p_i,q_j$ are already coprime.)
- Or, all $(p_i, q_j)=R$. Now, using the Lemma above multiple times we can conclude that $(p,q)=(p_1\cdots p_n,q_1\cdots q_m)=R$, which is a contradiction with the assumption that $(p,q)$ is not principal.

$\blacksquare$

Comment: I have checked carefully, there is no  problem. Thanks.