# Under what conditions can Noetherian /artinian rings be considered principal ideal domain.

Tags: ring-theory, noetherian, principal-ideal-domains

*Background*

**Definition 1:** A ring $R$ is said to satisfy the $\textbf{ascending chain condition}$ ($\textbf{ACC}$) for left (right) ideals if for each sequence of left (right) ideals $A_1, A_2, \ldots$ of $R,$ with $A_1\subset A_2\subset\ldots$ there exists a positive integer $n$ (depending on the sequence) such that $A_{n}= A_{n+1}=\ldots$. $R$ is said to satisfy the **descending chain condition}** (**DCC**) for left (right) ideals if for each sequence of left (right) ideals $A_1, A_2, \ldots$ of $R,$ with $A_1\supset A_2\supset\ldots$ there exists a positive integer $n$ (depending on the sequence) such that $A_{n}= A_{n+1}=\ldots$.

**Definition 2:** A ring which satisfies the ACC for left (right) ideals is called a **left** (**right**) **Noetherian ring**.

**Definition 3:** An integral domain $R$ satisfies the **ascending chain condition** on **principal ideals** provided that whenever $(a_1)\subset (a_2)\subset(a_3)\subset\ldots$, then there exists a positive integer $n$ such that $(a_i)=(a_n)$ for all $i\geq n$.

**Lemma 1:** Every principal ideal domain $R$ satisfies the ascending chain condition on principal ideals.

*Questions:*

In the above three definitions, and the lemma, i cited the definition of what a Noetherian/Artinian ring is and also that in an integral domain, a principal ideal domain satisfies the ascending chain condition.  I tried to find out if given a ring that satisfies the ascending chain condition or descending chain condition, under what circustances can such a ring be made into a principal ideal domain.  I know such a ring has to be at first an integral domain.  I try looking up at the text Examples of commutative rings by Harry C. Hutchins.  There is also
the more advanced text Chain condition in Commutative rings by Ali Benhissi.  I was not able to find anythign.  As a matter of fact, I tried looking up in various algebra text trying to find under what condition can a ring be consider to be a principal ideal domain.  But I am not able to find any theorems about it.  I am wondering if any of the expert algebraists in the community can shed light on the matter.

Thank you in advance

Comment: -1 every time I see you continue to abuse mathjax and using it to format text.

Comment: A domain is a [PID $\iff$ Bezout & ACCP](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/218516/242), $ $ and for a UFD $D\,$ [TFAE:](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1245196/242) $\,\ (0)\ D$ is a PID. $\,\ (1)\ {\rm  dim}\, D \le 1.$ $\,\ (2)$ prime ideals are primcipal. $\,\ (3)$ max ideals are principal. $\,\ (4)\ \gcd(a,b)=1\Rightarrow (a,b)=(1).$ $\,\ (5)\ D$ is Bezout. $\ \ $