# Constructing DVR's from arbitrary UFD's

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Is the following statement true?

> Let $A$ be an UFD and $p\in A$ prime, then $A_{(p)}$ is a discrete valuation ring.

I think yes: For every element $x$ of $Q(A_{(p)})=Q(A)$, there is a unique $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that I can write $x$ as $p^k\cdot\frac{a}{b}$ for some $a,b\in A$ with $p\nmid a,b$. This should give me the well-defined valuation $\nu\colon x\mapsto k$ from $Q(A_{(p)})$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ such that $A$ is the valuation ring associated to $\nu$. Then $\nu$ is surjective, because for every $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ we have $p^k\mapsto k$.

But now I am confused since this would imply that $A_{(p)}$ is Noetherian without further assumptions, which for me seems to come out of nowhere. So is the above argument correct? And if so, is there a more direct way to see that $A_{(p)}$ should always be Noetherian?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $p$ is nonzero and prime, $(p)$ [is a height one prime](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/816893/116766), and so $A_{(p)}$ is a one dimensional local UFD, since localizations of UFD's are UFD's. But [a one-dimensional UFD is noetherian](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/403653/116766). Thus, since UFD's are integrally closed, $A_{(p)}$ is an integrally closed noetherian local domain of dimension one, hence is a DVR.

Comment: The maximal ideal is principal, and every other ideal is a power of the maximal ideal.

Answer (score 2):

Let me complement the nice and abstract existing answer by a  concrete one:

Yes, the argument is correct.  To see that the ring $A_{(p)}$ is noetherian directly use an argument as you might know it from Euclidean domains.

Let $I$ be an non-zero ideal. Let $a \in I$ be non-zero with minimal valuation, say $k$; then show $I = (a) $, as for $b \in I$ you have $a^{-1}b$  has non-negative valuation and thus is in the ring.

Thus, this is a PID and thus noetherian.

Or, show further that $(a)= (p^k)$ so all non-zero ideals are given by $(p^k)$ with $k$ a natural number and there cannot be an infinite ascending chain as there is no infinite descending chain of natural numbers.

Comment: If $A$ is a local UFD, then every ideal is a power of the maximal ideal.