# Does "zero dimensional domains are fields" require the Boolean Prime Ideal theorem?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, axiom-of-choice, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Consider the following simple lemma:

> **Lemma 1.** Let $R$ be a commutative domain, then $R$ is a field *iff* $\dim(R)=0$.

**N.B.** By "commutative domain" I mean ''nonzero commutative ring with 1 such that $xy=0$ implies either $x=0$ or $y=0$'' and "dimension" means "Krull dimension". $(\!\!\implies\!\!)$ is unconditionally true. The proof I know for $(\!\!\impliedby\!\!)$ involves the existence of maximal ideals and thus Zorn's lemma. This initally led me to wonder:

> **Wrong question:** is the axiom of choice (in the form that every proper ideal is contained in a maximal ideal) required to prove **Lemma 1**? Is **Lemma 1** even equivalent to the axiom of choice?

---

After searching the internet for clues I stumbled on this [MathOverflow question on the existence of prime ideals](https://mathoverflow.net/q/98549/13700) and [godelian's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/98558/13700). The following doesn't require any choice principle:

> **Lemma 2.** Let $R$ be a nonzero commutative ring with $1$, then $R$ is a field *iff* its only ideals are $(0)$ and $(1)$.

So to prove that zero dimensional domains are fields it is enough to prove that their only ideals are $(0)$ and $(1)$. If there were some proper ideal $(0)<I<(1)$ then, by the Boolean Prime Ideal (BPI) theorem, the quotient ring $R/I$ would have a prime ideal which pulls back to a prime $(0)<I\leq \mathfrak{p}$ in $R$. Thus $\dim(R)\geq 1$ which is a contradiction.

> **Better question:** is BPI required to prove **Lemma 1**? Is **Lemma 1** strictly weaker than the BPI?

---

One can slightly broaden the scope of the question by dropping the domain condition and asking

> **Slightly broader question.** Does "prime ideals in zero dimensional rings are maximal" require the BPI? Is it possibly even equivalent to the BPI? Or is it weaker?

One can ask a broader question still without mentioning dimensions:

> **Alternative phrasing.** What choice principle is required to prove that prime ideals which are maximal among prime ideals are maximal among all proper ideals.

Comment: I was a bit surprised by the question before I realised that you're talking about the Krull dimension. As a side note: every compact Hausdorff topological ring with unity is zero-dimensional (= totally disconnected), e.g. p-adic integers.

Comment: @tomasz Yes, I agree about primes rather than maximals for $\impliedby$. Unless I'm misunderstanding your point it's already incorporated in the question.

Comment: Yes, I see that now. I was confused by your first claim that the proof you know involves maximal ideals, but I guess that is just because this is the easiest way to find prime ideals in ZFC.

Comment: @tomasz sorry for the confusion. You're right: I'd heard of the BPI theorem but I never "used" it until raising this question.

Comment: Near-duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2193852/is-the-axiom-of-choice-necessary-to-prove-that-closed-points-in-the-zariski-topo

Comment: In particular my answer there shows that some amount of AC is needed, though I don't know if it requires the full strength of BPI.

Comment: Thank you for that link @EricWofsey it's a really interesting argument! I'd heard it said a couple of times that rings of meromorphic functions have interesting/peculiar properties as rings, but I must admit I never paid much attention. Your argument producing a nonprincipal ultrafilter on $\Bbb{N}$ out of a nonzero element in a prime ideal in $B$ is really compelling. So the domain $B$ which isn't a field _can_ be zero dimensional...

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your Lemma 1 is equivalent to the Boolean Prime Ideal Theorem.
$\DeclareMathOperator{\colim}{colim}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Spec}{Spec}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Atoms}{Atoms}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Primes}{Primes}
\newcommand{FinSetSurj}{\mathsf{FinSet}_{\mathrm{surj}}}
$

We work in ZF with the axiom that every commutative domain is either a field or has a nonzero prime ideal. We are given a nonzero Boolean ring $B$ and the aim is to produce a prime ideal of $B.$

The plan is to transform each finite subring of $B$ to adjoin a zero prime ideal to the spectrum. I will describe the underlying problem as the construction of a contravariant functor
from the category of finite sets and surjections, to the category of commutative rings with unity
$$G:\FinSetSurj^{\mathrm{op}}\to\mathsf{CRing}$$
such that each ring $G(A)$ is a domain whose nonzero prime ideals are naturally isomorphic to $A.$
More specifically, for finite sets $A$ define $T(A)$ to be the topological space on the set $A\cup \{*\}$ where the elements of $A$ are closed points, and $*$ is a new point whose closure is the whole space. On morphisms $T$ just extends by sending $*$ to $*.$ The topological space $\Spec(G(A))$ is required to be homeomorphic to $T(A),$ naturally in $A.$

Assuming for now the existence of $G$ the rest of the argument is mostly formal. Let $I$ be the directed set of finite subrings of $B$ ordered by inclusion. All the following colimits range over $R\in I,$ and the limits range over $R\in I^{\mathrm{op}}.$ Let $\Primes:\mathsf{CRing}\to \mathsf{Set}^{\mathrm{op}}$ be the functor that takes a ring to its set of primes i.e. the underlying set of the prime spectrum. Let $\Atoms:I\to \FinSetSurj^{\mathrm{op}}$ be the restriction of $\Primes$ to subrings of $B.$ There are bijections
\begin{align*}
\Primes(B)
&\cong\Primes(\colim R)\\
&\cong \lim \Atoms(R)\\
&\cong \lim (T(\Atoms(R))\setminus\{*\})\\
&\cong (\lim T(\Atoms(R)))\setminus\{*\}\\
&\cong (\lim \Primes(G(\Atoms(R))))\setminus\{(0)\}\\
&\cong \Primes(\colim G(\Atoms(R)))\setminus\{(0)\}
\end{align*}
where I’m abusing $*$ to mean the element of the limit that sends each $R$ to the $*,$ and similarly for $(0).$ The second and final bijections are the fact that $\Primes$ takes directed colimits of rings to limits in $\mathsf{Set}$ - see https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/078L. To check that $C=\colim G(\Atoms(R))$ is not a field, fix some $R\in I$ and pick any nonzero element $x$ in any nonzero prime ideal of $G(\Atoms(R)).$ Because the connecting maps $\Primes(G(\Atoms(S)))\to\Primes(G(\Atoms(R)))$ are surjective, the connecting maps $G(\Atoms(R))\to G(\Atoms(S))$ take $x$ to an element of a prime ideal, which means $x$ is not  invertible in $C.$ A directed colimit of domains is a domain. So by assumption the last set in this chain of bijections is nonempty, which means the first set $\Primes(B)$ must be non-empty, QED.

The existence of $G$ is a problem of “inverting Spec” solved by *M. Hochster*, [**Prime ideal structure in commutative rings**](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=251026), *Trans. Amer. Math. Soc.* **142** (1969), 43--60. Theorem 6(a). I am not sure if those rings would be domains, but quotienting by the unique minimal prime ideal should do. To make this answer more self-contained, and to relieve any anxiety over whether Hochster’s result requires ZFC, I will also describe a construction of $G.$

Define $G(A)$ to be the ring of rational functions in the indeterminates $X_a,$ $a\in A,$ such that the denominator is not divisible by any $X_a.$ In other words, take the polynomial ring on $\{X_a\}$ with rational coefficients, and localize at the set of primes $\{(X_a)\}.$ This removes all the prime ideals except for $(0)$ and each $(X_a).$ For each surjection $f:B\to A$ we need to define a map $G(f):R(A)\to R(B)$ such that the preimage of $(X_b)$ is $(X_{f(b)}).$ Define $G(f)$ on each fraction $p/q$ by substituting each variable $X_a$ by $\prod_{f(b)=a} X_b.$ Observe that distinct monomials are sent to distinct monomials (this is where we need $f$ to be surjective). If every monomial of $G(f)(q)$ is divisible by $X_b,$ then every monomial in $q$ is divisible by $X_{f(b)},$ which was disallowed in the definition of $G(B).$ So $G(f)$ is well defined. The functoriality of $G$ is straightforward.

**Remark.** I will mention a few properties of this specific $G.$ The rings $G(A)$ are PIDs so the ring $C=\colim G(\Atoms(R))$ is a Bézout domain. The rational number coefficients could be replaced by any fixed base field. The ring $C$ can alternatively be described as the monoid algebra over the monoid $\colim \mathbb N^{\Atoms(R)},$ localized at the set of polynomials that are not divisible by any nontrivial monomial.