# UFD iff PID in Dedekind domain.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $A$ be a Dedekind domain. PID implies UFD. So for the other direction assume $A$ is an UFD. In this [proof](http://planetmath.org/pidandufdareequivalentinadedekinddomain) the author only considers prime ideals instead of any proper ideal. Why is this sufficient?

Comment: In the case where $A$ is Dedekind every ideal is a product of prime ideals and the product of principal ideals is principal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, [an integral domain in which every prime ideal is principal is a PID](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/168082/an-integral-domain-whose-every-prime-ideal-is-principal-is-a-pid).

In the case of Dedekind domains, the story is much simpler. Every ideal factorises (uniquely) as a product of prime ideals. Since a product of principal ideals is principal, it is sufficient to show that prime ideals are principal.