# All prime ideals of size less than the Minkowski bound being principal implies that the ring of integers is a PID

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ideals

So I am currently learning about ideal class groups and it is mentioned by the professor that to "show that the ring of integers $R$ is a PID, it suffices to show that all prime ideals of size less than or equal to the Minkoski bound is principal" I don't understand why this is the case and would appreciate if somebody can explain it to me.

From what I understand, the ideal class group $Cl(R)$ consists of all ideals in the ring of integers $R$ (where R can be shown as a Dedikind domain). Hence, all ideals in $Cl(R)$ have a finite unique factorization into prime ideals.

At the same time, the ideal class group $Cl(R)$ can be shown to be equal to the quotient group $J_K/P_K$ where $J_K$ is the group of fractional ideals of the ring of integers of $K$, and $P_K$ is its subgroup of principal ideals.

Any assistance on how I should proceed will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The class group $CL(K)$ is generated by prime ideals of norm at most $M_K$, the Minkowski bound. Therefore the claim follows. See for example [here](https://bpb-us-e1.wpmucdn.com/s.wayne.edu/dist/1/24/files/2020/05/MAT-7410-The-Class-Number-1.pdf), page $4$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I see..... But I don't see how every prime ideal of norm at most $M_k$ being principal implies that $CL(K)$ is trivial i.e. every ideal in $K$ being trivial.

Comment: No, trivial class group just means that they are all principal. Class number $1$ means PID for the ring of integers.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Oh yes. You are right. But I still dont see how every prime ideal of norm at most $M_k$ being principal implies that $CL(K)$ is trivial i.e. all the ideals are principal.

Comment: For an integral domain, if all prime ideals are principal, so is every ideal, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/168082/an-integral-domain-whose-every-prime-ideal-is-principal-is-a-pid).

Comment: I see. That makes sense. Thanks!