R is UFD. R is PID if every prime ideal is principal.
Suppose not. We consider the set of all non-principal ideals, $S$. Order $S$ by inclusion. We show S satisfies all the conditions in Zorn's Lemma. So it has a maximal element. If we show the maximal element say, $I$ is prime, then it would mean $I$ is principal by hypothesis, which is a contradiction.
Suppose $I$ is not prime, then there exists a pair $a$ and $b$ such that $ab \in I \implies a \notin I, b\notin I$. Consider ideals $I + (a)$ and $I + (b)$ by maximality they are principal.
How to go further in proving this, also nowhere I used R is a UFD. Please help.

In fact, the hypothesis that $R$ is a UFD is unnecessary; we only need $R$ to be a domian. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/168082/an-integral-domain-whose-every-prime-ideal-is-principal-is-a-pid for a completion of your proof.
