# A maximal element of the set of non-principal ideals is prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $R$ be a ring which is not a PID. The set $S$ of all ideals of $R$ which are not principal has a maximal element with respect to the inclusion (Zorn's Lemma), I already proved this! Now, I need to show that if $P$ is a maximal element of $S$, then $P$ is prime.

I tried by contradiction: suppose $a,b \not\in P$, but $ab \in P$. So $P+(a)$ and $P+(b)$ are not in $S$, and therefore they are principal ideals, say $P+(a) = (x)$ and $P+(b) = (y)$. Now, I just need to show that $P$ is principal. Any hint will be helpful.

Thus, I will conclude that for any ring, if all prime ideals are principal, then any ideal is principal.

Comment: I believe $S$ is the set of ideals which are NOT principal.

Comment: Yes! $S$ is the set of ideals which are NOT principal.

Comment: Showing $P$ is principal would give a contradiction.  Another approach: If you can show $ab+P$ is not principal it violates the maximality of $P$.

Comment: There seems to be a confusion here, since what you want to see is that if a ring has nonprincipal ideals it has nonprincipal prime ideals, so you want to show your maximal element, which I'll denote by $\mathfrak p$, is prime. It is nonprincipal by definition, since it is a maximal element of a collection of nonprincipal ideals.

Comment: I think that $ab + P = P$, since $ab \in P$.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2674507/if-u-is-maximal-among-non-principal-ideals-show-that-u-is-prime-hints).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this [link](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05K7) (includes proofs). Two steps:

1. The family of principal ideals of a ring is an Oka family.
2. If $\cal F$ is an Oka family of ideals, then any maximal element of the complement of  $\cal F$ is prime.

In ring $R$, a set of ideals $\cal F$ is an *Oka family*  if $R\in \cal F$ and whenever $I$ is an ideal such that $(I:a)\in \cal F$ and $(I,a)\in \cal F$ for some $a\in R$, then $I \in \cal F$.

Pedro Tamaroff-suggested other good link is [here](https://math.berkeley.edu/~lam/html/ams-oka2.pdf). Also the ones pointed out by Bill Dubuque in an MSE answer (for another standard Oka family, ideals that do not intersect a given multiplicative subset in the ring) [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66192/instructive-proof-of-if-i-is-maximal-among-ideals-not-then-i-is-prime/66194#66194).

Comment: A good source is [this one](https://math.berkeley.edu/~lam/html/ams-oka2.pdf), too.

Comment: See also the [links here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/66194/242)

Comment: @ir7 This solved my problem completely. Thanks!

Comment: For those who are wondering (like myself) $(I:a) = \{ r\in R : ra\in I \}$