# Maximal element of a subset of ideals is often prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

In Richard Borcherds' (excellent) lectures on Youtube, he mentioned on a couple occasions that when one wants to construct a prime ideal with a certain property, a good strategy is to look at the set of ideals with that property, and very often a maximal element of this set is prime. For example (beyond the obvious example that maximal ideals are prime), he used this to show that for any ideal $I$ of a commutative ring and multiplicative subset $S$ such that $S\cap I=\emptyset$, there is a prime ideal containing $I$ that does not meet $S$.

Can this be formalized? I.e., is there a condition on a subset of the set of ideals of a (commutative) ring that would ensure that a maximal element (if it exists) is prime?

Comment: Yes: [A Prime Ideal Principle in commutative algebra](https://math.berkeley.edu/~lam/html/JAlg-PIP.pdf) by Lam and Reyes

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/66194/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/44488/242) and probably many other answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this was done quite masterfully in a few papers by Reyes and Lam using the notions of Oka and Ako collections:

[A prime ideal principle for two-sided ideals](http://arxiv.org/abs/1501.06808)

[Noncommutative generalizations of theorems of Cohen and Kaplansky](http://arxiv.org/abs/1007.3701)

[A one-sided Prime Ideal Principle for noncommutative rings](http://arxiv.org/abs/0903.5295)